# Flask/ jinja2 empty spaces and tags not in place

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

So, I'm trying to use flask/jinja2 template and I'm having trouble with variables rendered not in the correct place and weird empty char.

`base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(146, 173, 196);">
    {%- block body -%}{%- endblock -%}
</body>

</html>
```

`home.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%- block body -%}
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(70, 162, 255);"></div>
{%- endblock -%}
```

`Result`

[image: code render]

[image: HTML render]

1. The first problem is that "﻿ " comes from nowhere but renders as an empty char.
2. The `title` tag renders inside the `body` tag instead of in the `head`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding! The problem was using UTF-8 BOM encoding, which was fixed by converting the template file to UTF-8.

[More details from W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.en.html)